# Table not overflowing properly - Power BI Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, format, powerbi, report, builder

Below is what I have versus what I want. I have a report that has a dynamic table (Blue and black boxes surrounded by red). The first two pictures show that when it expands, it overflows onto the next page horizontally onto the exact same height of the page.

The problem seems to be an overflowing column group. The black and blue boxes are the dynamic column groups.

I want the 3rd picture that has the table expand appropriately, but overflow vertically so it stays on the same page as long as possible. Enough space definitely isn't the problem, but I can't seem to find an option that will make this world, I feel I've toggled everything.

Thank you!

[image: What I Have]
[image: What I Have Pg 2]
[image: Desired]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the matrix inside of a list. Move the dataset and filters from the matrix to the list. You probably know how many column groups should show up on each row. Take that number, here it looks like 2, and set this as the GroupBy for the list's row group:
`=Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/2)`