# Power BI report Builder - Divide overflowing matrix row

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder

I have a dynamic row of attributes associated with customer. Number of attributes for each customer may vary from 3 to n.

I am trying to display it in a row but if number of attributes increase from 3 to 10 data over flows from right to left on a page. For example

Attribute 1 | Attribute 2  | Attribute 3 | Attribute 4  | Attribute 5 | Attribute 6 | Attribute 7

Is it possible to start a new row for attributes after fixed number of columns, lets say 4?

Attribute 1 | Attribute 2 | Attribute 3 | Attribute 4
Attribute 5 | Attribute 6 | Attribute 7

I found similar question [Table not overflowing properly - Power BI Report Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306670/table-not-overflowing-properly-power-bi-report-builder) but steps mentioned in answer are not clear.

Edit:

**Design view:**

[image]

**Report View**
[image]

**TEST**

I tried adding colum/row groups but doing that creates a matrix like this
[image]

**Desired View**

first 4 attributes to be rendered on 1st row and next 3 attributes to be rendered on second row

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the current report design and our current output (with sample data if possible). I can probably answer your question but with a little more info I can make sure it's correct but I waste time giving you a wrong answer

Comment: data set is ID and ATTRIBUTE. I have nothing in my report except one matrix cell. I created it through a matrix wizard and removed additional cell to have just the ATTRIBUTE cell. When I run it, it runs perfectly with a single row and all the 9 attributes that I have in my current dataset

Comment: I just added screenshots for your reference @AlanSchofield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would normally do something like this is to calculate the row and column numbers in the dataset query, then you can use these values as the row and column groups.

The following query creates some sample data, just `ID` and `Attribute` and then returns that same data along side the RowN and ColN columns which hold the row and column numbers respectively.

I've also parameterised this so you can easily adjust the number of generated columns.

The sample data contains data for 3 unique IDs, each with a different number of attributes.

**Note:** the attributes are named such they can be ordered alphabetically, you may have to adjust the three instances of the `ORDER BY` clause to get the order correct with your real data (if it matters).

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID int, Attribute varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(1, 'Attribute 01'), (1, 'Attribute 02'), (1, 'Attribute 03'),
(2, 'Attribute 01'), (2, 'Attribute 02'), (2, 'Attribute 03'), (2, 'Attribute 04'), (2, 'Attribute 05'), 
(3, 'Attribute 01'), (3, 'Attribute 02'), (3, 'Attribute 03'), (3, 'Attribute 04'), (3, 'Attribute 05'), (3, 'Attribute 06'), (3, 'Attribute 07'), (3, 'Attribute 08'), (3, 'Attribute 09'), (3, 'Attribute 10'), (3, 'Attribute 11')

DECLARE @MaxCols int = 5

SELECT 
    ID, Attribute,
    RowN = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Attribute)-1) / @MaxCols,
    ColN = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Attribute)-1) - (((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Attribute)-1) / @MaxCols) * @MaxCols)
 FROM @t
```

This gives us the following results (clipped for brevity)

[image]

Now we can create a simple matrix as per the design below. (Note the two row groups and one column group)
You can remove the RowN column (but not the group), I left it in for clarity..

[image]

When we run the report using 5 as the `@MaxCols` value we get this..

[image]

and settings the `@MaxCols` value to 4 gives us this.

[image]